# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP hangs before clearing all activities?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity stack like this A -> B -> C. I am launching activity A with clear top from C. Now what happens is it will finish C instantly, then it will resume A, then about 2 seconds later it will finish B. I am confused what is causing this two second delay before killing activity B.

Answer (score 0):

It's on feature of Android: first create new Activity for user to see, later finish the previous old activity...